# Syntax coloring for Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting

I'm planning to do a Cocoa app that requires code syntax to be colored (in all common languages). Instead of writing my own code highlighter/parser, are there any pre-made solutions available?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a Cocoa app that highlights code entered by a *user*, or you want to write a Cocoa app with the source for *that* app syntax highlighted? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: I think he needs to highlight code entered by a user (Plus he said "in all common languages", I doubt he wants to use PHP, ruby, python and perl in his application :D)

Comment: naixn is corrrect, thats what I want to do. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be able to use something like [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), but there're also the resources listed here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SyntaxHighlighting

*Edit*

More links:

- [Syntax Highlighting in Cocoa TextView? Experiences? Suggestions? Ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972812)
- http://parsekit.com/okudakit/

Comment: Geshi is written in PHP. It would be tedious to integrate into a Cocoa app. Drilling through your second link; this is relevant: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ImplementSyntaxHighlighting

Comment: Good links, will check them out

Answer (score 3):

An excellent solution is Uli Kusterer's [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm#UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument). It is fast and has several built-in syntax parsers. It's easy to add new languages.

It's free for non-commercial use and very cheap if you want it for a commercial app.

Comment: Wow can't believe I didnt find this before. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the JavaScript library [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) and embed it into a WebView into your app.

Comment: If I can get this working in a webview, that would work brilliantly :D

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of research trying to solve a similar problem, the simplest approach I found by far is to use a JavaScript library for syntax highlighting combined with a WebView. Spending time writing a syntax highlighter, a fairly complex task, is probably not what you'd want to spend time on.

I settled on using the popular [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and wrote an open source wrapper for Cocoa: https://github.com/swisspol/CodeMirrorView. You can use similar approaches to wrap other JavaScript based code editors in Cocoa apps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/index.html) that is used in [QLColorCode](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/wiki/ReadMe) :) (however, it's not a Framework that you include in your code, but a command-line utility)

EDIT: Ah yeah, use Geshi, it's probably better :D

Comment: This is an application that syntax-highlights code. The questioner wants to make the application he or she is writing highlight code.